# Create DOM element from Object in javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, object, element

Hi I'm trying to understand how to make Dom elemnt, let's say "div" form my data Object.
I've made an object like this:

```
var div = {

        style : {
            width: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
            height: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
            position: "relative",
            top:Math.floor(Math.random()*500)
        },

        sayHi: function () {
            alert("Hello");
        },

    }
```

What I need to do now, is to make it live element in DOM with these css params?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var DOMdiv = document.createElement("div");
for(var key in div) {
    if(key === "style") {
        for(var cssstyle in div[key]) {
            DOMdiv.style[cssstyle] = div[key][cssstyle];
        }
    } else {
        DOMdiv[key] = div[key];
    }
}
document.body.appendChild(DOMdiv);
```

But keep in mind that this Div has now a function called `sayHi()` attached to it. There is no eventhandler initiated or whatsoever. If you like to have some eventhandlers, change your object like that:

```
var div = {

     [...]


     onclick: function() {
         alert("Hi");
     }

 };
```

Comment: Or use a custom event handler if you want more than one click event. Or just use jQuery™.

Comment: *"`var DOMdiv = document.create("div");`"* That should be `createElement`, not just `create`.

Answer (score 3):

To create a DOM element, you use `document.createElement`, like this:

```
var elm = document.createElement('div');
```

That `elm` will already have a property called `style`; you can then assign to its members, e.g.:

```
elm.style.width = div.style.width + "px"; // Remember this is CSS, you need units
```

A [`for..in` loop](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/11/myths-and-realities-of-forin.html) on your `div.style` might be useful there, but do be sure to handle the units thing.

To attach event handlers to it, you can do the old DOM0 thing of assigning to `onXyz` properties, like this:

```
elm.onclick = div.sayHi;
```

...which will make it run the `sayHi` function on click, but a more modern way is via `addEventListener`:

```
elm.addEventListener('click', div.sayHi, false);
```

Older versions of IE don't have `addEventListener`, but they do have its MS-only predecessor, `attachEvent`:

```
elm.attachEvent('onclick', div.sayHi);
```

Note the difference in the event name, and it doesn't have the third argument.

All of this is academic unless you add `elm` to the page somewhere. :-) You can do that by getting a reference to another element on the page, and then calling `appendChild`:

```
someOtherElement.appendChild(elm);
```

More to explore:

- [DOM2 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/)
- [DOM2 HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/)
- [DOM3 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/)
- [HTML5 Web Application APIs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#webappapis)

---

Because of things like the `addEventListener` / `attachEvent` browser incompatibility and various other small things, and because they offer a lot of pre-packaged utility functionality, a lot of people (including me) use a JavaScript library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries) to help with this stuff.

Comment: Would `elm.style = div.style` work? Just curious. Assuming the units are correct of course.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine: I don't *think* so, but I'll admit I've never tried it.

Comment: I don't think it will. Chrome's console shows that elm.style is a 'CSSStyleDeclaration', where div.style is just an Object. I've tried using jQuery's $.extend, hoping that it'd simply fill in the properties of the style, but this didn't work :(